# $Fm = (I+\Delta tK)^{-n_t}m$ - Knowing eigenvalues of K, can I find eigenvalues of F?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm working with the inverse problem for the 1D heat equation, $F(m) = u(x,T)$, and using the 2nd order centered finite difference method the problem is discretized using a mesh with $h = \frac{L}{n_x}$ and with $\Delta t = \frac{T}{n_t}$. Then we get the $(n_x-1)\times(n_x-1)$ matrix F and the following:

$$Fm = (I+\Delta tK)^{-n_t}m$$
$$K = \frac{k}{h^2} \begin{bmatrix}2&-1&&&\\-1&2&-1&&\\&-1&2&-1&&\\&&...&...&...\\&&&-1&2&-1\\&&&&-1&2\end{bmatrix}$$

I've been told that the eigenvalues of K are

$$\mu_n = k\frac{4}{h^2}sin^2\left(\frac{n\pi jh}{L}\right)$$

and I'm trying to find the eigenvalues of F. Is the following legitimate?

$$ \begin{align} (I+\Delta tK)^{-n_t}x & = \lambda x \\ (I+\Delta tK)x&=\lambda^{n_t}x\\ \Delta tKx&=(\lambda^{n_t}-1)x\\Kx &= \frac{\lambda^{n_t}-1}{\Delta t}x\end{align} $$

$$.:\mu_n = \frac{\lambda^{n_t}-1}{\Delta t}$$

$$\lambda_n = (\mu_n\Delta t+1)^{-n_t}$$

Comment: You might want to search 'tridiagonal Toeplitz matrices'. [Here](http://www.math.kent.edu/~reichel/publications/toep3.pdf) is something to get you started. I'm also sure there is a proof for the eigenvalues somewhere on this site, though I couldn't find the link for you.

Comment: Thank you! Looking into it now!

Comment: No worries. Also, the first 8 pages of [this](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/wtrench/research/papers/TRENCH_TN_12.PDF) detail how to find the eigenvalues by examining the recurrence relations. It is probably the easiest to follow.